# RecyclerView Child Items scroll events and click events

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, click

Is there any method to temporary disable recyclerview child items clickable and scrollable?

```
recyclerView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
```

By using this, I am able to stop the scrolling events but I have no idea how to disable the child items clicks event.

Comment: Use an `if` statement inside the `onTouch`?

Comment: @TomJames if touch event occurs then disable click? But the ontouchlistener is for recyclerview, not for the child items.